# How do I remove "offset" below task bar?

Tags: taskbar, windows-11

There is a "offset" or gap below my Windows 11 task bar, the task bar is not at the very bottom of the screen.

How can I push the task bar to the bottom of the screen?

Thanks for your help,

[image: Image. A screenshot showing a Windows 11 task bar. There is a visible gap between the bottom of the task bar and the bottom of the screen. Typically, there would be no gap, the two edges would be flush]

Answer (score 0):

Solution: surprisingly, unplugging and replugging the monitor fixed the issue!